# Property comparison query with date object returns object while properties don't match

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-orm

I have a domain class in `Grails` as follows:

```
class ActivityEvent
{
    String activityName 
    Date startTimeStamp
    Date endTimeStamp
    Client client

    static belongsTo = [client: Client]

    static constraints = {
        activityName            nullable:false, blank:false, size: 0..50
        startTimeStamp          nullable:false
        endTimeStamp            nullable:false
        client                  nullable:false
    }
}
```

where `Client` is another domain class.

In my test I save 2 `ActivityEvent` objects to the db:

```
Date now = new Date()
Client c = Client.get("1")
new ActivityEvent(client: c, activityName: "test", startTimeStamp: new Date(now.getTime()), endTimeStamp: new Date(now.getTime())).save(failOnError: true)
new ActivityEvent(client: c, activityName: "test", startTimeStamp: new Date(now.getTime()), endTimeStamp: new Date(now.getTime() + 5 * 60 * 1000)).save(failOnError: true)
```

Now when I execute (with `c` and `name` being parameters to this method)

```
ActivityEvent.findAll {
    client == c &&
    activityName == name &&
    startTimeStamp == endTimeStamp
}
```

My resultset is this:

```
[
  ActivityEvent - name:test from Mon Oct 27 09:37:56 CET 2014 to Mon Oct 27 09:42:56 CET 2014,
  ActivityEvent - name:test from Mon Oct 27 09:47:56 CET 2014 to Mon Oct 27 09:47:56 CET 2014
]
```

As you can see the resultset contains an `ActivityEvent` with the `startTimeStamp` not being equal to the `endTimeStamp` while I did specify this in my query that they need to be equal.

When I run the same query using `where`

```
ActivityEvent.where {
    client == c &&
    activityName == name &&
    startTimeStamp == endTimeStamp        
}.find()
```

I get an exception `org.hibernate.NonUniqueResultException: query did not return a unique result: 2` which is no surprise since the `findAll` also returns 2 objects.

Am I missing something or doing something wrong in the query? According to the printout of the resultset one item shouldn't have matched the query.

Comment: You may try logging SQL queries and looking into the database.

Comment: I did that, the SQL query turns out to be okay, and so is executing the query in, for example, MySQL Workbench

Comment: That's weird. What if you run these criterias in a `grails console`?